# How do I install a program on an external drive while using it on my computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-recovery, help-files

I'm looking to recover files from my laptop.

I don't want to install the recovery software on the internal HDD, and instead on an external drive (like a USB flash drive) and operate the software on the laptop.

Is this possible? Or should I install recovery software on a different computer and plug in the HDD that has the deleted file to that computer?

Answer (score 1):

So called "portable Software" can run directly from a external drive, no installation on the host system is necessary. Most recovery software can create a bootable CD / flash drive / etc. you can boot from to use it.

**IMPORTANT**: If your laptop has only one HD and you are using it, your chances of recovering the files will get slimmer! In this case turn it off and make a 1:1 backup of the HD before you try anything else.

Comment: But what do you think is a better idea: to install recovery software on an external drive and use the computer with the deleted file to run it, or plug the internal HDD onto another computer that has the recovery software and do it from there?

Comment: @NowOS usually plugging it into a different PC is a better choice for recovery (but make sure to make 1:1 backup anyway)

Comment: How do I make a 1:1 backup?

Comment: @NowOS lot's of explanations out there, look for "how to make a HD image sector by sector"

Comment: Is it possible I can make a digital clone of my HDD?

Comment: @NowOS yes, it would be s.th. like that